# Why do I get a "object reference requested" with this event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'm trying to use a custom event raised from a second thread. Here are the relevant parts of the code :

```
delegate void SearchCompleteHandler(Dictionary<string, List<string>> results);
event SearchCompleteHandler SearchComplete;

public static void Search()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    SearchComplete?.Invoke(result);
}

SearchComplete = new SearchCompleteHandler(ShowSearchResults);
SearchComplete += new SearchCompleteHandler(ShowSearchResults);
dupeSearchThread = new System.Threading.Thread(Search);
dupeSearchThread.Start();
```

I get an error at this line :

```
SearchComplete?.Invoke(result);
```

VS says that "an object reference is required for this non-static property" (approximate thanslation).

I thought that adding a Handler to the event before using it would be sufficient. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you're referencing an object that is not static at all: you should remove the keyword static from the Search method in order for it to be accessible within the instance of your class and thus enable it to access all the variables and objects instantiated in it.